# Python Flask NoAppException: While importing "microblog", an ImportError was raised:

Tags: python, flask

`__init__.py`

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
from app import routes
```

`microblog.py`, `set FLASK_APP=microblog.py`

```
from app import app
```

`app.py`

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
from app import routes
```

`routes.py`

```
from app import app

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return "Hello, World!"
```

`run.py`

```
#!flask/bin/python
from app import app
app.run(debug=True)
```

When I do `flask run` I get:

```
flask.cli.NoAppException
NoAppException: While importing "microblog", an ImportError was raised:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 235, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "C:\Users\ACER\FlaskTEST\venv\app\MicroBlog\microblog.py", line 1, in <module>
    from app import app
  File "C:\Users\ACER\FlaskTEST\venv\app\MicroBlog\app\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from app import routes
  File "C:\Users\ACER\FlaskTEST\venv\app\MicroBlog\app\app.py", line 4, in <module>
    from app import routes
ImportError: cannot import name routes
```

Comment: Organize better your code and also add your project folder structure in order to help you

Answer (score 6):

From the python module names I'm assuming you're working on the [Flask Mega-Tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world) created by Miguel Grindberg.

The directory structure of the Mega-Tutorial is as follows:

#### Current_Working_Directory:

- `microblog.py`
- a folder/directory named `app`

#### Current_Working_Directory/app:

- `__init__.py`
- `routes.py`

---

Note here the two differences between your python modules and Miguel's:

1. You have a duplicate file named `run.py` that performs the same thing as his `microblog.py`. To fix, you can either keep `run.py`, place it in the current working directory, and `set FLASK_APP=run.py` OR you can delete `run.py` and use `microblog.py` when calling `flask run` which will run what you set as the `FLASK_APP`.
2. You have an unnecessary python module named `app.py`, delete this and you should be good to go.

Remember you can always view [Miguel's Microblog GitHub](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/microblog/tree/v0.1) to double check your code matches his at the end of each chapter.